# Pull specific data from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote a function wheere I need to store some data in database.
I have multidimensional associative array.

I dumped one part of the code..

When I dump:

```
            $csv->setCode($data[7]);

            dump($data[7]);die;
```

and I get

```
"{"id":"131-2-0-615317","o":"raccoon-events-ltd","j":"Member of the...","c":"Sport For All..."}"
```

Now, I need to pull out just the "ID" part of the code..

I just tried:

```
dump($data[7]=>id);die;
```

Comment: That looks like a JSON string, so you would have to _decode_ the JSON first, so that you get actual data objects.

Comment: An aside `dump($data[7]=>id);die;` isn't even valid PHP.

Comment: ^^ what Jon said. That should have given an error. Errors turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its JSON
use this code:

```
$json = json_decode($data[7],true);
dump($json['id']);die;
```

Comment: Thank's lot. This did it.